# Mantis Bug Tracker - What is default Admin password after fresh installation?

Tags: bug-tracking, mantis, bug-tracker

I installed Mantis BT and was redirected to login page after successful installation. It says that default user is 'administrator' but gives no hint about its password. [Documentation](http://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/administration_guide/admin.install.new.html) has not specified default password either. Any clue?

[image]

Comment: I put 'java' tag.. That doesn't seem right. Removed it. Ok.

Answer (score 36):

Aah.. Got it.. Default password is 'root'

It is working. Found [here](http://www.ramonfincken.com/44/PHP+coding/%5Bsolution%5D+What+is+the+mantis+bugtracker+default+admin+password+after+installing.html)..

Comment: I have installed mantisBT 2.22.1, and using username as 'administrator' and password root but its giving me an error  "Your account may be disabled or blocked or the username/password you entered is incorrect", please let me know if you have any solution.